# Are these unwraps necessary?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm new to Rust and I see a lot of code looks like this:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("So we start the program here!");
    let t1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(200));
        println!("We create tasks which gets run when they're finished!");
    });

    let t2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        println!("We can even chain callbacks...");
        let t3 = thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50));
            println!("...like this!");
        });
        t3.join().unwrap();
    });
    println!("While our tasks are executing we can do other stuff here.");

    t1.join().unwrap();
    t2.join().unwrap();
}
```

As you can see, they invoke `join()` followed by `unwrap()`, but they don't use the unwrapped stuff. I tried deleting these `unwrap()` and it still works. Are these `unwrap()` necessary? I also noticed even the Rust book use this syntax.

Comment: `join()` returns a `Result`.  Are you familiar with [how `Result` works](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/type.Result.html) and [the error-handling paradigm they represent](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)?  Think about what would happen with and without `unwrap` in the event that `join()` failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `unwrap()` is a shorthand to access the value of a Result or an Option. It's fine when you write some example code as you don't want to deal with the error handling. And if you remove the `unwrap()` here everything is going to work.

It would be different if for some reason an error will be returned.
In this case, your program will behave differently, with the `unwrap()`, or without.

In the case you  have the `unwrap()`, the error condition will exit the program.
If you don't use `unwrap()`, the program will go ahead ignoring the error.

As written before, this is fine for small piece of code, but in a real world scenario, the `unwrap()` should not be there, instead you should handle the error case.

Comment: I'd like to add that, in real-world code, if you *want* to hard-crash the program in case of error, you should use `expect()`, not `unwrap()`. It works the same but lets you provide a better error message that "Option was none".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo agree, it's just I didn't want to go much deeper on that part, as the OP was just about the unwrap behavior. Handling the error means even put an expect() to log if such a situation will occur. But you comment is right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a `panic!("bad!!!");` statement in thread `t1` and I found whether I use `t1.join().unwrap();` or `t1.join();`, I always got the output `thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'bad!!!'`. Does this contradict with your statement `If you don't use unwrap(), the program will go ahead ignoring the error.`?

Comment: @Justalearner If you use `panic!()` then you  are going to exit the program and you cannot recover by handling the error.

Comment: The output is printing from the thread `t1`. It's always going to panic `t1`. If you do the `unwrap`, you should get a second panic line saying something like "called Result::unwrap on Err value". This is coming from your main thread, which panicked on the unwrap.